# como deberia importar correctamente los modulos tk y ttk

Tags: python, tkinter

quiero usar un boton de tk y un combobox de ttk, los agrego y me sale 2 errores ya los comente de antemano

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.add_components()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def add_components(self):
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(root)#name 'root' is not defined
        self.boton = Button(root)#name 'Button' is not defined
        self.boton.pack()
        self.combo.pack()
app = Aplication()
```

Comment: No entiendo tu punto. Puedes importar tranquilamente ambos módulos sin "morir en el intento". Una forma hacerlo está en el código que está en la pregunta. Hay algo que se me pasó por alto?

Comment: Podrías agregar en la pregunta el error que te genera por favor?

Comment: Para poderte ayudar con tu problema, podrías agregar en la pregunta el código que pusiste en tu "respuesta" por favor? Por que verla me hizo pensar en una posible causa. Además también podrías agregar el mensaje de error que te muestra?

Comment: Todo esto lo digo para poder ayudarte con más facilidad

Comment: Para editar la pregunta, hay un botoncito abajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas que dice "editar".

Comment: lo que se ve en ese código son dos errores: 1) debes llamar a la ventana principal con self, o sea self.root y si bien has importado tkinter de forma correcta, eso no importa cada widget y hay que hacerlo como lo haces con ttk o sea primero tk  y luego .Button ej: tk.Button y así para cada elemento que quieras declarar

Comment: Además de lo que dijo tincopasan, creo que te hace falta entender como funciona la importación de modulos en Python. Te recomiendo la siguiente lectura: https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-3/creando-modulos-empaquetados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes importarlo de la forma:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

Si quieres importarlo de esa forma, tendrás que poner:

```
tk.Button, en vez de Button
```

Si no quieres los anteriores consejos, el primero lo solucionas con tk.Button, y el segundo con self.root, por lo que el código quedaría así:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.add_components()
        self.root.mainloop()
    def add_components(self):
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(self.root)
        self.boton = tk.Button(self.root)
        self.boton.pack()
        self.combo.pack()
app = Aplication()
```

Esto pasa porque root es parte de la clase self, tienes que indicarlo explicita mente. Además, Button es del módulo tkinter, o tk como lo re nombraste, y si no quieres poner explicita mente el "tk.Button" sino "Button", debes importarlo así:

````
from tkinter import *
```
````

Comment: gracias por la explicacion entendi bastante bien!!

Comment: Acepta mi respuesta si te ayude, eso me ayudaría a mi también.

Comment: Lectura recomendada para saber que hacer cuando alguien te da una respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Resalto que la forma de importar `from tkinter import *` es poco recomendado. Es algo que se hace mucho en tutoriales viejos.

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo tuve el mismo ploblema la forma mas comun de importarlo es :

```
         import tkinter as tk
         from tkinter import ttk
```